# Getting prints more than required in java

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, methods

I am working on a java code and I should use recursive methods and my methods should Search()  takes as parameters an array of Car objects ARR and a Car object C. This method
should return true if C is inside ARR, false otherwise.
b, method findCylinders that takes as parameters an array of Car objects ARR and number of cylinder
engine N. It should display all the cars that have N cylinder engine
My code is working fine but it keeps on printing the object many times.

```
public class Test_Car_Lab9{
   public static void main(String [] args){
      Car[] ARR = new Car[50];
      for(int i = 0; i < ARR.length; i++){
         ARR[i] = new Car(3500, 6, "Mazda", "MX6");
      }
      Car C = new Car(4700, 8, "Nissan", "Patrol");
      System.out.println(Search(ARR, C));
      findCylinders(ARR, 6);
   }
   public static boolean Search(Car[] carsArray, Car carObject){
      for(int i = 0; i < carsArray.length; i++){
         if(carObject.getMake() == carsArray[i].getMake() && 
         carObject.getModel() == carsArray[i].getModel() &&
         carObject.getCylinders() == carsArray[i].getCylinders() &&
         carObject.getHorsePower() == carsArray[i].getHorsePower())
            return true;
      }
      return false;
   }
   public static void findCylinders(Car[] carsArray, int numOfCylinders){
      for(int i = 0; i < carsArray.length; i++){
         if(carsArray[i].getCylinders() == numOfCylinders)
            carsArray[i].printCarData();   
      }
   }
}
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Does it print "infinite" or just "many times"? Those are kind of different. You added 50 Mazda MX6 with 6 cylinders into your array, so when searching for entries in your array with 6 cylinders you should kind of expect that it will find those 50 objects and prints each one.

Comment: Your problem is using == instead of String.equals for comparing String values

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS not infinite but many times yes.

Comment: Like 50 times? As I said you have an array with 50 times `Car(3500, 6, "Mazda", "MX6")` in it, so when you tell your program to search and output all cars with 6 cylinders getting that car printed 50 times is just the correct answer. Did you even intent to fill your array with 50 times the same car?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is doing == compare with Strings, instead of string equals.

```
   public static boolean Search(Car[] carsArray, Car carObject){
      for(int i = 0; i < carsArray.length; i++){
         if(carObject.getMake().equals(carsArray[i].getMake()) && 
         carObject.getModel().equals(carsArray[i].getModel()) &&
         carObject.getCylinders() == carsArray[i].getCylinders() &&
         carObject.getHorsePower() == carsArray[i].getHorsePower())
            return true;
      }
      return false;
```

Comment: It is not working until now.

Comment: While that is one problem I don't think it is the one responsible for OPs problem of "printing many times". The car they searched for in the example code isn't part of the array anyway, so the fact that the search method returned false was a ctually accidentally the correct result.

Comment: @OH GOD SPIDERS what do you suggest I do? Because I’m also required to make the array of 50 objects.